# htaccess redirect of url matching specific format

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The Bing bot shows that some of the url structure been misaligned
is it a way to forward all urls starting with ?id parameter after the domainname to redirect to home page. The id changes according to product page

```
http://www.abc.com/?id=100&itemid=2&option=com_toys&view=post - Incorrect url
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=post&id=100&Itemid=2 - correct url
```

Have tried using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/?id.*$
RewriteRule .*  index.php     [R=301,L]
```

but its not working, any suggestions to achieve the same !!

thanks

**Add on**

Hi - could you advise on one more on it

```
http://www.abc.com/index.php?Itemid=2&id=100&option=com_toys&view=post - Incorrect url
http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=post&id=100&Itemid=2 - correct url
```

That is if the pattern matches :- Itemid immediately after index.php, how to redirect it too to home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your rule with:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=.*
RewriteRule ^$  /?     [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi - Does not work, it results in this url -  http://www.abc.com/index.php?id=100&itemid=2&option=com_toys&view=post

Comment: yes i thought that's what you want, you wanna redirect it to the home page without the query string ( without id=...) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer so it does redirect to home page without query string (make sure to clear your browser cache)

Comment: Hi Amine, One more query on similar pattern is appended, could you see if can advise on it