# Domain name within domain name. How to redirect through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

The crawling properties of site showing

```
  http://www.abc.com/http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys
  http://www.abc.com/http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_article
  http://www.abc.com/http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_play&view=category&vid=10
```

The site been crawled like this, with errors coming in as duplicate url. Correct url is

```
  http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys
  http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_article
  http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_play&view=category&vid=10
```

is there any way to 301 redirect 
i tried using

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/http://www.abc.com.*$
  RewriteRule .*  index.php     [R=301,L]
```

But its not achieving the desired as redirecting to http://www.abc.com/index.php
How to redirect through htaccess from incorrect url to correct url sttructure off site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+http://.+?(/index\.php\?[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Works awesome as always. Wondering why is your reply deleted for this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526135/htaccess-redirect-of-url-matching-specific-format

Comment: Thanks. About the other link do you want some help for that (since you already have an accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://www.abc.com/index.php /index.php [QSA, R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, However your solution is doing the same thing only, redirecting to - http://www.abc.com/index.php. Like for incorrect url 1 as pointed out - http://www.abc.com/http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys, instead of redirecting to home page, it should redirect to correct url which is - http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys. May advise

Comment: Lucas, its redirecting the same to abc.com/index.php . Does not solve it